# Organizing scripts

Tags: php, html

I am reading http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

My question is, if I have an `index.php` that runs the `welcome.php` script, and the `index.html` has a certain design/layout, then I should add that design/layout to the `welcome.php`, as well. Isn't there an easier/better way to do it, without having to make a new file every time? Something like change lines of code in the `index.php` inside the `divs` but keep the rest of the design/layout?

Comment: You have a lot of ways to achieve that. Using includes, separating the header and footer on different php files, using a template system, using a framework...

Comment: So there is no best or most used way. Sorry, I'm a beginner. I want to do things by the book, the way they are usually done rather than what I think it's best.

Comment: Tip: don't read w3schools for the greater good.

Comment: If I understand correctly index.php contains your form and welcome.php is the script handling the form? If that is the case you have multiple options: 1) welcome.php, after having finished handling the form can redirect to index.php; 2) index.php and welcome?php can use templates for the common design/layot parts (google php template engine).

Comment: There is no "best" for all cases. For a little project or to start learning you can just use include/require. If you want to do it the right way at least use a template engine like twig and if you want to go further use a complete framework like Laravel or Symfony

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, The form will be inside a div, and when the script is run, that div's content changes from the form to the output of the script. Basicly, I was wondering if there is a way to do that without making 2 files. I'd like to not use a framework(it's a school project and I'm forbidden to using one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I understand your question better, I think I can give you an answer. It's not the best approach (like I said, templates and frameworks - as other users suggested, are the way to go), but since it's a school project, it should be ok.

Just use an empty string as the action for the form and it will use the same page to handle the form submission (the page containing the form). Then, in this page you check to see if the form has been submitted. If it hasn't, you show the form. If it has, you show the results. Like so:

```
<?php

//index.php
?>

<html>
<body>
    <div>
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])) :
        //form submitted
        if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
            echo "<p>Form submitted. Thanks, {$_POST['name']} !</p>" ;
        }
        else {
            echo "<p>Form submitted. Thanks, stranger !</p>" ;
        }
    else :
        //form not submitted 
    ?>
    <!-- no action means it will use current page = index.php for handling the form -->
    <form action="" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_button">
    </form>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would this approach be more "normal" than making other files for each page? Or it doesn't really matter?

Comment: Well using separate files (1 for the form, 1 for the form handling, 1 for the result) gets the point across more clearly as to what you are trying to do, but you asked for an easier way, which would be to use just one file.

Comment: The recommended way is to separate the html into a file and use templates for those files (that would be your VIEW). Use a separate file for calling the appropriate templates and for the logic of your program - in your case handling the form (this woul be your CONTROLLER). And there is also a third part which models your data, if you're working with a database (this would be your MODEL). These 3 combined are called an MVC model - google it, that is the norm.

Comment: Not easy, I asked for a normal, or most used way, without frameworks. Yes, I need to use MVC.